# How to describe inheritance of DTO in open api 3.0 to have java inheritance in generated classes?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, code-generation, swagger-codegen

I have 3 entities

```
parent 
 - child_1
 - child_2
```

And my openApi definition:

```
 Parent:
  description: Parent
  properties:
    id: 
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/id'
  
  Child1:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
      - type: object
        description: Child_1
        properties:
          child1Fied:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/child1Fied'

   Child2:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
      - type: object
        description: Child_2
        properties:
          child1Fied:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/child2Fied'
```

I expected to have generated classes like this:

```
Child1 extends Parent
...
Child2 extends Parent
...
```

But as a result all 3 classes are independent with their own fields (parent has id field, Child1 has his own id and child1Fied, Child2 has his own id and child2Fied).

Is there way to make a hint for code generator to implement classes via inheritance ?

**P.S.**
I haven't found answer here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/

Comment: For me the point of openapi-swagger is to provide the Description and constraints about JSON and REST.  There are no notion of inheritance in Json and in Json-schema and openAPI uses json-schema if i'm not wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034983/json-schema-vs-open-api-java-support

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but it works:

```
Parent:
   discriminator:
     propertyName: stub_type
   description: Parent
   properties:
     id: 
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/id'
```